# Eliminate duplicates based on Order By SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with more than 20 columns and more the 300.000 rows out of which the relevant columns for my question are the following:

```
column1 |column2 |column3 | date
   123  |  657   | 2222   | 20 dec
   123  |  658   | 2222   | Null
   124  |  543   | 3333   | Null
   124  |  544   | 3333   | 1 Feb
   125  |  098   | 4444   | Null
   125  |  065   | 4444   | Null
```

I did the following query to sort them as I needed:

```
select * 
from table
order by column1,column2,date desc;
```

The result is:

```
column1 |column2 |column3 | date
   123  |  657   | 2222   | 20 dec
   123  |  658   | 2222   | Null
   124  |  544   | 3333   | 1 Feb
   124  |  543   | 3333   | Null
   125  |  065   | 4444   | Null
   125  |  098   | 4444   | Null
```

The main purpose is to delete the rows where based on `column1` are duplicates if they have a date that is `not null`. If they both have `Null` then I sould be able to keep just one. So what I am looking for is this:

```
column1 |column2 |column3 | date
   123  |  657   | 2222   | 20 dec
   124  |  544   | 3333   | 1 Feb
   125  |  065   | 4444   | Null
```

Can someone help me to develop this query. I wish to retreive **ALL** of the other columns not just the ones displayed.

I am using Azure SQL which is basically SQL Server

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM table AS main
WHERE main.column4 IN
(SELECT sub.MinID FROM
   (SELECT column1, column3, min(column4) As MinID
    FROM table
    GROUP BY column1, column3) AS sub)
ORDER BY main.column1, main.column3;
```

The problem with this is that since the rule is `min(column4)` when I have a `Not Null` whose `column4` value is less than the other it choose the `NULL`. I tried putting `min(date)` but I get this error:
`Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type smalldatetime` I am guessing because of the `Null` values.

How can input the rule that if one is `Not null` and the other is `Null` then choose the `Not Null`

Comment: You need to specify how to decide which row to keep when there are multiple rows with the same value for column1. (Lowest Column 2 value? Lowest Column 3 value? what ?  whatever the rule is, it must be unambiguous, i.e., it must be a rule for which no more than one row per column1 value will satisfy.

Comment: @CharlesBretana thanks, the rule is based on the `date` column. If both are null, choose either else select the one that is `not null`. Where should I specify?

Comment: What if there are two not null, with different dates? and saying "choose either" is not doable. .You want the code to toss a coin ? you must specify a rule. When both are null, "choose the one with lower column2", or "Choose the one with greatest value of column3", or whatever. But you have to specify a rule.  and what if there are more than two rows with same column1?

Comment: Ok I understand. I need to specify that if both are `NULL` then choose one with a larger `column2` value. But how do I specify that if one is `NULL` and the other is `Not Null` to choose the one that is `Not Null`? Can you help me out with the code?

Comment: Based on the rule above **"I need to specify that if both are NULL then choose one with a larger column2 value"**... you should update your sample output because that appears to be doing the opposite i.e. returning 065 instead of 098.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like classic `top-n-per-group`. One way to do it is to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        column1
        ,column2
        ,column3
        ,dt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY dt desc, column2) AS rn
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    column1
    ,column2
    ,column3
    ,dt
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY
    column1
;
```

`PARTITION BY column1` means that numbering of rows restarts when `column1` changes. `ORDER BY dt desc, column2` determines the order when numbering the rows. In the end you just pick the first row of the partition using `WHERE rn = 1`.

The final result will have only one row per `column1`, so adding more columns to the final `ORDER BY` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Marvelous! I appreciate the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select * from table t
Where (date is not null
    and not exists 
     (select * from table 
      where date is Null
         and column1 = t.Column1)) Or
   column2 = 
     (Select Max(column2) from table
      Where column1 = t.Column1)
```

Answer (score 0):

CTE is probably your best bet:

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT column1
        ,column2
        ,column3
        ,DATE
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY 
                date
                ,column1
                ,column2
                ,column3 DESC
            ) AS RN
    FROM table
    )
DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <> 1
```

To check that what you are deleting is the correct data, just change DELETE to SELECT * at the end.